# Express version output

Tags: node.js, express

I upgraded [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) from 3.2.5 to 3.14.0, and used to output the version like this:

```
var express = require('express');
console.log("**Express Version: ", express.version);
```

and would give me

```
**Express Version:  3.2.5
```

after I updated to 3.14.0, I get:

```
**Express Version:  undefined
```

any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using @FreeTymeKiyan's answer as well as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750985/1696153

I found that I can output the version like so:

```
console.log("**Express Version: ", require('express/package').version);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that version property is removed from express object in 3.14.0. You may check it with `console.log(express);`

So there is probably no good way to get it with your original code. A workaround is to get the version in package.json file.

```
var pkgInfo = require('./package.json');
console.log(pkgInfo.dependencies.express);
```

If there is any strange sign before the version number, try remove that sign at the beginning of the string.

```
console.log(pkgInfo.dependencies.express.substr(1));
```