# Socket.IO Version Output

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I upgraded [socket.io](http://socket.io/) from 0.9.16 to 1.0.6, and used to output the version like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
console.log("**Socket.IO Version: "+io.version);
```

and would give me

```
**Socket.IO Version: 0.9.16
```

after I updated to 1.0.6, I get:

```
**Socket.IO Version: undefined
```

any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
console.log("**Socket.IO Version: " + require('socket.io/package').version);
```

The idea is to load `package.json` file, which contains information about a Node package.

This is possible because Node's `require` is able to load JSON modules as well.
From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

> If the exact filename is not found, then node will attempt to load the required filename with the added extension of `.js`, `.json`, and then `.node`.
> `.js` files are interpreted as JavaScript text files, and `.json` files are parsed as JSON text files [...]